# Making bivariate colour ramp with QGIS

Tags: qgis, color-ramp, design

Many recent maps I have seen have these neat two-way colour gradients that can be used to colour correlations between continuous estimates.

Here is an example is taken from a recent publication.

*Christian Levers, Pieter J. Verkerk, Daniel Müller, Peter H. Verburg, Van Butsic, Pedro J. Leitão, Marcus Lindner, Tobias Kuemmerle* - Drivers of forest harvesting intensity patterns in Europe. Elsevier. 1 March 2014 (access: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.foreco.2013.12.030).

[image: Example]

I believe those gradients have been generated with ArcGIS 10.x and I was wondering how I could reproduce such colour gradients with freely available GIS tools (or at least those available on Linux)?

Comment: Good timing. http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/

Comment: Indeed! @Vesanto - You should perhaps consider posting it as an answer along with simplified instructions from your link.

Comment: I am especially puzzled how to do it with continuous  predictors vertically and horizontally and how to generate the legend for it afterwards

Comment: That tutorial only covers distinct colours. And the legend would be added in afterwords in gimp for example.

Comment: Done in QGIS: https://www.flickr.com/photos/115987875@N04/15311770866/in/pool-qgis using two distinct ramps and then adjusting blending modes, but it is not truly correct. Also the legend is just two legends overlaid.

Comment: If you are interested in an approach using R you may want to take a look at [this blog post](https://procomun.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/maps_with_r_1/)

Comment: This QGIS plugin seem the perfect answer : https://jancaha.github.io/qgis-plugin-bivariate-renderer/ (it does the symbology and create the legend in the print composer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Excellent answer by @Martin but it seems you have 2 attributes you want to have a colour gradient (*Plantation Cover* and *Forest Harvesting Intensity*). If I'm mistaken then I will remove this post. You could set up a **Rule-based** style, create a new rule, edit the symbol layer from a **Simple Fill** to a **Gradient Fill**. Create a filter for your attribute column and set your colours. Then repeat by adding another style rule:

[image: Gradiant fill]

[image: Rule-based style]

Comment: +1 Ohh yes, forgot the gradient fill options. But how to color it with both a vertical and horizontal gradient as shown in the example figure of my question?

Comment: That's a good question! Just a thought as I haven't tested this before but you could try using a Single Style (not Rule-based), select the **Gradient Fill** and set the colours via **Data defined properties**. Not sure if this will work but it _may_ give you a single gradient legend.

Comment: Great answer. I didn't know this function :)

Comment: Thanks @Martin =). I actually never used the gradient option but remembered it was there because of your post (never intended to steal your answer!)

Comment: Nono seems like my answer is not complete, so thank you for adding this ;)

Comment: No, this does not work. When I do like shown above, then every cell looks like my "label 1" with "label 2" not visible because it is below label 1. Maybe this function got screwed up in a newer release?   :(

Comment: This doesn't work, as @Jens said the colors shown are merely whichever the symbol level with highest order.

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 2.6 you can create a two color color ramp this way:

`Double click on the layer (or right click > Properties) > Style > 
Change from "Single Symbol" to "Categroized" > Color Ramp > Random colors> 
Select Gradient > Choose the colors and safe > 
Choose the column with the values > Classify > Apply`

[image]

In the "Column" field you have to select the column containing the values that should be displayed in the color ramp.

Comment: This is not a bivariate color ramp and does not answer the original question.